# Authenticate to Google Container Registry with Podman

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, podman

The Google Container Registry [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) provides very good help on authenticating to it with Docker. Is there a way to do the same with [Podman](https://podman.io/)? The Google doc mentions Access Token as a method. Maybe that could work. If anybody has any advice or experience of this, I'd really appreciate your help

Comment: gcloud auth print-access-token | podman login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://XX.gcr.io. the xx.gcr.io is the host name. for example http://us.gcr.io etc [use this doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#linux--macos)

Comment: @cam your comment should be an answer!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
gcloud auth print-access-token | podman login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin XX.gcr.io
```

`xx.gcr.io` is the host name. For example `https://us.gcr.io`, etc.

`oauth2accesstoken` is a special username that tells it to get all identity information from the token passed as a password.

[See this doc.](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#linux--macos)

Comment: `gcloud auth print-access-token --quiet` was necessary because `gcloud` wanted me to take a survey.